# Twilio Client Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, twilio

I'd like to know why there isn't a npm / yarn package to [Twilio Client Javascript SDK 1.4](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.min.js).
I'm trying to use their voice service, following [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/node/programmable-voice) tutorial, but in React Native.

Is this package for browser usage only? How could I have access to `Twilio.Client` on react-native?

I already implemented a programmable-chat with success, using the provided packages `twilio-chat` and `twilio-common`.

Meanwhile, is there any way of importing a remote file or using a local javascript file (twilio.min.js) to a react-native app?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Further research lead me to believe that this SDK only work for browsers since it has to deal with audio events, connection status etc. 
Correct me if I'm wrong. 
I'm now trying to implement [react-native-twilio-programmable-voice](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice) 
.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio ?

Comment: @xDreamCoding thats the package for twilio-node, twilio server side package. Not the twilio client.

Comment: Twilio Client JS actually came out before the growth in popularity of npm as a method of distributing front end packages. That doesn't mean we won't investigate that for the future. In the meantime, you have found a package that would help better as it wraps the native libraries for each platform.

Comment: @philnash but as it is now, would this package work on react-native? Or browser only. I mean, I see loads of people trying to integrate your services in react-native.
Majority of the people in the RN world don't really know objective-c / java and can't integrate the native modules. Plus, this package isn't maintained by Twilio

Comment: The existing JavaScript package was build specifically for browser JavaScript. I'm not familiar enough with React Native's internals to know whether features like WebRTC are supported within its runtime. We don't currently officially support any cross platform wrappers for our SDKs, so we do rely on community contributions like react-native-twilio-programmable-voice.

Comment: @philnash I opened a new Issue regarding twilio voice, if you could take a look please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812414/twilio-voice-sdk-show-friendlyname-on-call