# Twilio Voice SDK - show FriendlyName on call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

So, I'm now able to create a voice call (voip, no phone numbers) using the Twilio Sever JS SDK, executing the following code:

```
makeCall : function(req, res) {
    req.checkBody({
        'To' : {
            notEmpty : true,
            errorMessage : 'Invalid To'
        }
    });

    req.getValidationResult().then(function(result) {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            res.status(400).json(responseHandler.errorResponse("INVALID_FIELDS", result.mapped()));
            return;
        }

        const twimlRes = new Twiml.VoiceResponse();

        const dial = twimlRes.dial()

        dial.client(req.body.To);

        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        res.send(twimlRes.toString());
    });
}
```

However on my phone and CallKit features (iOS) I only have access to a client ID, is there any method to update the ID to a friendlyName on `getToken` or on even on `dial` / `VoiceResponse` ?

I already tried to follow [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids#update-an-outgoing-caller-id) but I think it only applies to phone numbers? Correct me If I'm wrong but I have no `outgoingCallerIds`..

**EDIT:** I also tried to add a callerId in the dial method:

```
twimlRes.dial({ callerId: 'Jose' })
```

But on my phone on my phone I have a transformed string which looks like the corresponding phone key numbers `5673` (Jose).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far in iOS? Getting the ID to show as a friendly name is more the job of the iOS application rather than the TwiML app webhook.

Comment: Ah, I see you've opened an issue on the react-native-twilio-programmable-voice repo. Hopefully that will get you an answer. There's definitely [code in the project that does set caller names in CallKit](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice/blob/839a1602d4cccf07b1dabb0df41077a86b2d3cbc/ios/RNTwilioVoice/RNTwilioVoice.m#L503).